Unable to open Sql Database project in VS 2022 or 2019
I have VS.Net solution in which multiple projects are there, which all are opening fine, but the SQL Project where we have SQL Files is not opening, if I am trying to open it in VS 2022, it is giving me the following error message

The imported project "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
was not found. Also, tried to find
"Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) -
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in
"C:\Users\devadminam\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_6d8b140c\devenv.exe.config".
Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
C:\SourceCode\Reporting Media Services Dev\Source\WSD
3212\RptMediaService\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj

When I am trying to open it in the VS 2019, it is giving the following error message

C:\SourceCode\Reporting Media Services Dev\Source\WSD
3212\RptMediaService\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj
: error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
Visual
Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
was not found. Also, tried to find
"Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) -
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in
"C:\Users\devadminam\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_5464bbaa\devenv.exe.config".
Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
C:\SourceCode\Reporting Media Services Dev\Source\WSD
3212\RptMediaService\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj

Not able to figure out what mistake did I make, previously it was opening fine, for a while I was busy with other stuff, it started giving me errors above.
The db project file is as below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <Name>CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database</Name>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectVersion>4.1</ProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{6e64f941-bf54-41f6-be0b-a178c3b692f9}</ProjectGuid>
    <DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
    <OutputType>Database</OutputType>
    <RootPath>
    </RootPath>
    <RootNamespace>CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database</AssemblyName>
    <ModelCollation>1033, CI</ModelCollation>
    <DefaultFileStructure>BySchemaAndSchemaType</DefaultFileStructure>
    <DeployToDatabase>True</DeployToDatabase>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetLanguage>CS</TargetLanguage>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <SqlServerVerification>False</SqlServerVerification>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseSet>True</TargetDatabaseSet>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildScriptName>$(MSBuildProjectName).sql</BuildScriptName>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties" />
    <Folder Include="bin" />
    <Folder Include="bin\Debug" />
    <Folder Include="dbo" />
    <Folder Include="dbo\Functions" />
    <Folder Include="dbo\Stored Procedures" />
    <Folder Include="dbo\Tables" />
    <Folder Include="dbo\Views" />
    <Folder Include="Import Schema Logs" />
    <Folder Include="obj" />
    <Folder Include="obj\Debug" />
    <Folder Include="Security" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="bin\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.dacpac" />
    <None Include="bin\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.dll" />
    <None Include="bin\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.pdb" />
    <None Include="Import Schema Logs\CalSTRS.Services.Rpt_20161017104151.log" />
    <None Include="obj\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.dll" />
    <None Include="obj\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.pdb" />
    <None Include="obj\Debug\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj.FileListAbsolute.txt" />
    <None Include="obj\Debug\Model.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnCompareFilterPermissions.sql" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnDecodeSignedNumeric.sql" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnEditCanBeEmployerApprovable.sql" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnEditRunEditIsEmployerApprovable.sql" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnEmployerApprovedEditsExistForFileLineDetail.sql" />
    <Build Include="dbo\Functions\SfnEmployerApprovedEditsExistForFileLineDetailAndEdit.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And I have the solution file as below
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.10.35013.160
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{38758AFE-4B04-4168-922B-6FA683555A12}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        localtestrun.testrunconfig = localtestrun.testrunconfig
        Reporting Media Services.vsmdi = Reporting Media Services.vsmdi
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.csproj", "{4A7D1AB9-5DDD-4FFD-B2E1-723C4207B611}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business.csproj", "{52573895-33E4-49B1-BEF2-5F6926A16890}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.csproj", "{D4805742-D470-42B2-AF42-1FEA695E4872}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.Start", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.Start\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.Start.csproj", "{73899FA3-25AF-432B-A3DF-04E8DE77BC78}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Entity", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Entity\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Entity.csproj", "{1140E470-5876-4AAB-9E1C-39B7A226B392}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper.csproj", "{4D611562-B4DB-4817-857A-B9F2954A425B}"
    ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject
        {271BF624-FA12-4558-87D2-8606EC5EC5BC} = {271BF624-FA12-4558-87D2-8606EC5EC5BC}
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ConsoleApplication", "ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication.csproj", "{041A8C27-E86E-4255-A643-6C0FC1C6A530}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility.csproj", "{FCB4D741-E36F-4505-9CB5-B4B4087E5319}"
EndProject
Project("{00D1A9C2-B5F0-4AF3-8072-F6C62B433612}") = "Database", "Database\Database.sqlproj", "{4B85C4ED-8DE8-4B89-9045-462DE5AC1E88}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "TransferFilesToNetworkService", "TransferFilesToNetworkService\TransferFilesToNetworkService.csproj", "{5C436A63-7D49-4311-8783-332680038E46}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "TransferFilesToNetwork", "TransferFilesToNetwork\TransferFilesToNetwork.csproj", "{706022B6-05EF-48D0-B836-818A2299733F}"
EndProject
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "CalSTRSRptMediaServices", "http://localhost/CalSTRSRptMediaServices", "{271BF624-FA12-4558-87D2-8606EC5EC5BC}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        SccProjectName = "SAK"
        SccAuxPath = "SAK"
        SccLocalPath = "SAK"
        SccProvider = "SAK"
        UseIISExpress = "false"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2"
        ProjectReferences = "{52573895-33E4-49B1-BEF2-5F6926A16890}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business.dll;{D4805742-D470-42B2-AF42-1FEA695E4872}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.dll;{73899FA3-25AF-432B-A3DF-04E8DE77BC78}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Data.Start.dll;{4A7D1AB9-5DDD-4FFD-B2E1-723C4207B611}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.dll;{1140E470-5876-4AAB-9E1C-39B7A226B392}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Entity.dll;{FCB4D741-E36F-4505-9CB5-B4B4087E5319}|CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility.dll;"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/CalSTRSRptMediaServices"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "CalSTRSRptMediaServices\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\CalSTRSRptMediaServices\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/CalSTRSRptMediaServices"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "CalSTRSRptMediaServices\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\CalSTRSRptMediaServices\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "CalSTRSRptMediaServices\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test.csproj", "{F7AF0CB9-F06C-4B72-950C-B1A2D58A7EEE}"
EndProject
Project("{00D1A9C2-B5F0-4AF3-8072-F6C62B433612}") = "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database", "CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj", "{6E64F941-BF54-41F6-BE0B-A178C3B692F9}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "_build", "_build", "{D6E2CEB1-EBA9-413C-99B0-D7997572431E}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "NugetPackageRptMedia", "NugetPackageRptMedia\NugetPackageRptMedia.csproj", "{15BF3989-39D3-4327-8198-6C8DCA897F7A}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|.NET = Debug|.NET
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|Mixed Platforms = Debug|Mixed Platforms
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        DemoMode|.NET = DemoMode|.NET
        DemoMode|Any CPU = DemoMode|Any CPU
        DemoMode|Mixed Platforms = DemoMode|Mixed Platforms
        DemoMode|x86 = DemoMode|x86
        Development|.NET = Development|.NET
        Development|Any CPU = Development|Any CPU
        Development|Mixed Platforms = Development|Mixed Platforms
        Development|x86 = Development|x86
        Release|.NET = Release|.NET
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|Mixed Platforms = Release|Mixed Platforms
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
        SingleProjectDebug|.NET = SingleProjectDebug|.NET
        SingleProjectDebug|Any CPU = SingleProjectDebug|Any CPU
        SingleProjectDebug|Mixed Platforms = SingleProjectDebug|Mixed Platforms
        SingleProjectDebug|x86 = SingleProjectDebug|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution     
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {15BF3989-39D3-4327-8198-6C8DCA897F7A} = {D6E2CEB1-EBA9-413C-99B0-D7997572431E}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {6D6D6F8F-5638-415F-BF47-D0481A83CC83}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 16
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://tfs:8080/tfs/calstrsappcollection
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business.csproj
        SccProjectName1 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business
        SccLocalPath1 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Business
        SccLocalPath4 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Entity
        SccProjectUniqueName5 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper.csproj
        SccProjectName5 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper
        SccLocalPath5 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.ServiceHelper
        SccProjectUniqueName6 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility.csproj
        SccProjectName6 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility
        SccLocalPath6 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Utility
        SccProjectUniqueName7 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.csproj
        SccProjectName7 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia
        SccLocalPath7 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia
        SccProjectUniqueName8 = ConsoleApplication\\ConsoleApplication.csproj
        SccProjectName8 = ConsoleApplication
        SccLocalPath8 = ConsoleApplication
        SccProjectUniqueName9 = TransferFilesToNetwork\\TransferFilesToNetwork.csproj
        SccProjectName9 = TransferFilesToNetwork
        SccLocalPath9 = TransferFilesToNetwork
        SccProjectUniqueName10 = TransferFilesToNetworkService\\TransferFilesToNetworkService.csproj
        SccProjectName10 = TransferFilesToNetworkService
        SccLocalPath10 = TransferFilesToNetworkService
        SccProjectUniqueName11 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test.csproj
        SccProjectName11 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test
        SccLocalPath11 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Test
        SccProjectUniqueName12 = Database\\Database.sqlproj
        SccProjectName12 = Database
        SccLocalPath12 = Database
        SccProjectUniqueName13 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database\\CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database.sqlproj
        SccProjectName13 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database
        SccLocalPath13 = CalSTRS.Services.RptMedia.Database
        SccProjectUniqueName14 = NugetPackageRptMedia\\NugetPackageRptMedia.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName14 = Reporting\u0020Media\u0020Services.sln
        SccProjectName14 = NugetPackageRptMedia
        SccLocalPath14 = NugetPackageRptMedia
        SccWebProject15 = true
        SccProjectUniqueName15 = http://localhost/CalSTRSRptMediaServices
        SccProjectName15 = CalSTRSRptMediaServices
        SccLocalPath15 = CalSTRSRptMediaServices
        SccProjectEnlistmentChoice15 = 2
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal

Can somebody please help me what is wrong in my project or solution, thank you so much please. I tried to reduce the post size by removing some details, if you feel is it is needed, I can provide. If the project can be opened in either 2019 or 2022, anyone env is fine. Thank you so much.

This has been fixed after manually updating the SSDT folder path as below for VS 2022, in my machine v12.0 folder didn't exist, I had v17.0, so updated accordingly.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\SSDT
If anybody needs help
